# Select last 20 order by ascending - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table structure

```
MyTable
ID[P.K][auto increment]   TopicID   UID   Comment
```

Now i want to get the last 20 comment for a TopicID but it should be sorted in ascending order !

[Just like Facebook by default shows last 20 comment only]

*I am looking for an optimized version, i can do this with 2/3 query and php sort array, but looking for some better alternative*

`Sample Result with data`

```
MyTable  
ID TopicID UID Comment  
1  1       10  AAAA   
2  1       11  BBBB  
3  1       10  CCCC  
4  1       10  dddd   
5  1       11  EEEE  
6  1       10  FFFF
```

I want to get the last 3 result for a TopicID, the result should be

```
4  1       10  dddd   
5  1       11  EEEE  
6  1       10  FFFF
```

and not

```
6  1       10  FFFF  
5  1       11  EEEE  
4  1       10  dddd
```

Comment: What field are you trying to sort by?

Comment: i want to sort the result by ID ascending

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First, select last 20 entries. Then sort them in ascending order. You can easily do this in a single query (with subquery):

```
select * from (
    select * from your_table order by id desc limit 20
) tmp order by tmp.id asc
```

Comment: The use of a subquery here is unnecessary. Subqueries are expensive and almost never necessary. You can achieve the same results by running only the subquery and then printing them in reverse order on the PHP side.

Comment: Subqueries are often misused. They are indeed expensive when used in list of selectable fields (`select id, name, (subquery) as something from table`) or in `where` clause (`select id, name from something where foo = (subquery)`), but it's OK to use them as source of data.

Comment: @eykanel - nonsense. Mapping the data inot PHP and sorting it outside the database is wasteful and innefficient. It's also a waste of programmer time

Comment: It can be done much easier:
`(select * from your_table order by id desc limit 20) order by id asc;`
As usual you can omit the "asc".

Comment: @jpsy Thank you :-)

Comment: It all gets tricky when adding ORM tools with automatic pagination to the mix (such as Laravel query builder with paginate() ) because it adds the limit outside of the entire query. So sometimes you have to do in PHP, but it's no big deal - just sort DESC in SQL and then  array_reverse in PHP. I doubt that array_reverse is that much slower than the subselect in SQL.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   topicid = $mytopicid
        ORDER BY
                id DESC
        LIMIT 20
        ) q
ORDER BY
        id
```

or, more efficiently,

```
(
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   topicid = $mytopicid
ORDER BY
        id DESC
LIMIT 20
)
ORDER BY
        id
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be the shortest expression to do the job:

```
    (select * from your_table order by id desc limit 20) order by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT * FROM MyTable
   ORDER BY ID DESC
   LIMIT 20) ilv
 ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand??

What's wrong with a simple `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE TopicID = 1 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 20`?

By the way, if you're showing the latest entered ones (ie. most recent), you'll want `DESC` (Descending), not `ASC`. Also, using the ID is very unreliable, you should have a `DATETIME` column which stores when the comment was entered.

EDIT: [binaryLV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912770/select-last-20-order-by-ascending-php-mysql/5912827#5912827) will do this correctly using a subquery. It's the same query as mine, `DESC`'d, and then resorted by ID.

Comment: He needs last 20 entries, ordered in asc. Like "5, 6, 7" (rather than "7, 6, 5") from "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a CommentDate Column and everytime you INSERT a comment use `NOW()` or `GETDATE()` then use this select:

```
SELECT Comment FROM MyTable WHERE TopicID=@ID ORDER BY CommentDate DESC, TopicID ASC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Yeah, but he does not need *first* entries.

Comment: @binaryLV What you mean, Look at my query now

Comment: @Danpe, I mean that he needs to select *last* entries (with largest CommentDate).

Comment: By the way, if he uses `timestamp` column to store date, he can set its default value to `current_timestamp`. It's not necessary to fill it manually with `now()` or `getdate()`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that ID is auto_increment, which would allow you to use it as a pseudo-date field,

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY ID DESC
  LIMIT 20
```

Comment: I like the idea about sorting by `id` (that's what I usually do). Though, result of this query won't be sorted as author needs it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT TOP 20 * FROM TableName
    ORDER BY Id DESC
)
Naushad ORDER BY Naushad.Id
```

Comment: The question is tagged MySQL, your script would work for SQL-Server.