# How to select last 5 rows order by id ascending - CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to get last 5 record order by ascending.

I have a table name `chat_public_msgs` there are i have inserted 6 Sample data. I need last 5 record order by id asc. Please check below.

Table `chat_public_msgs` -

```
id  username  message  created
1    smith   hi        2014-12-14 10:14:15   
2    piter   hello     2014-12-14 10:14:20    
3    john    hi smith  2014-12-14 10:14:28
4    raj     aaa       2014-12-14 10:15:22
5   chinu    test      2014-12-14 10:15:25  
6   piter    bbbbb     2014-12-14 10:15:40
```

Query -

```
$fields = array('ChatPublicMsg.message','ChatPublicMsg.created','ChatPublicMsg.username');
$results = $this->ChatPublicMsg->find('all',array(
           'fields'=>$fields,
           'limit'=>5, 
           'order'=>array('ChatPublicMsg.id ASC')));
```

Output-

```
id  username  message  created
1    smith   hi        2014-12-14 10:14:15   
2    piter   hello     2014-12-14 10:14:20    
3    john    hi smith  2014-12-14 10:14:28
4    raj     aaa       2014-12-14 10:15:22
5   chinu    test      2014-12-14 10:15:25
```

But I want this-

```
id  username  message  created  
2    piter   hello     2014-12-14 10:14:20    
3    john    hi smith  2014-12-14 10:14:28
4    raj     aaa       2014-12-14 10:15:22
5   chinu    test      2014-12-14 10:15:25  
6   piter    bbbbb     2014-12-14 10:15:40
```

***Edit -***

i got this query from [Select last 20 order by ascending - PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912770/select-last-20-order-by-ascending-php-mysql)

```
select * from (
    select * from chat_public_msgs order by id desc limit 5
) tmp order by tmp.id asc
```

How can i write above query in CakePhp format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by sorting the result by 'id' DESC and limiting the number of records to 5. Then use array_reverse() to reverse the sorting.

```
$fields = array('ChatPublicMsg.message','ChatPublicMsg.created','ChatPublicMsg.username');
$results = $this->ChatPublicMsg->find('all',array(
       'fields'=>$fields,
       'limit'=>5, 
       'order'=>array('ChatPublicMsg.id DESC')));
$reverse = array_reverse($results['ChatPublicMsg']);
$results['ChatPublicMsg'] = $reverse;
```

This assumes that 'id' is incremented with each record. Otherwise you need to add a timestamp field to the table and use this field for sorting.