# Select last 5 records and sort them ascending in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'd like to select last 5 records in table and sort them ascending. First i'd like to say that I'm aware of sollutions for this question already provided on stackoverflow (like [Select last 20 order by ascending - PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912770/select-last-20-order-by-ascending-php-mysql)). What i have problem with is to make them work in PDO. Here is my code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=somedb;port=3306', 'someuser', 'somepassword');
$stmval = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID, col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 WHERE `col4` = 1 ORDER BY col3 DESC LIMIT 5) tmp ORDER BY col3 ASC" );
$stmval -> execute();
while($somesome = $stmval -> fetch())
{
echo $somesome ['col1'].",".$somesome ['col2'].",".$somesome ['col3'];
}
```

So basicly it works until I add extra SELECT * FROM (SELECT [...]) inside prepare()
how can i select last 5 elements in table and sort them ascending using PDO?

Lets say i have array:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
I select by mysql last 3 element so i need o use DESC ordering. I have:
10,9,8
now i take it and make it ascending so final result is what i desire:
8,9,10
Problem is whenever i try to modify second line of my code:

```
stmval = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT [...] ORDER BY col3 DESC" );
```

to

```
stmval = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM (SELECT [...] ORDER BY col3 DESC) ORDER  BY col3 ASC" );
```

it just wont work for some reason.

Comment: What are you ordering by ASC ??

Comment: sorry just corrected it - I order by col3

Comment: So now what's the problem?

Comment: OK. I get it now. Hm, I'm not sure why that it !?!?

Comment: I've checked again. I cannot replicate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot replicate your findings.

In MySQL:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT ID
            , col1
            , col2
            , col3 
         FROM table1 
        WHERE `col4` = 1 
        ORDER 
           BY col3 DESC LIMIT 5
     ) tmp 
 ORDER  
    BY col3 ASC;
+----+------+------+------+
| ID | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  9 |   27 |   13 |   81 |
| 10 |   68 |   97 |   82 |
| 23 |   22 |   71 |   88 |
|  6 |   35 |   81 |   99 |
| 16 |   77 |   46 |  100 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

In PHP:

```
27,13,81
68,97,82
22,71,88
35,81,99
77,46,100
```

Comment: I've just noticed error in my code and managed to find the answer but still your example helped me a lot. Sorry it was just a missed column name in middle select as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I;ve managed to figure this out and I'm a bit ashamed I could miss it.

My problem was that below code worked cause you do not have to SELECT col3 to ODRED BY it:

```
$stmval = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT col1, col2 FROM table ORDER BY col3 DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Howether in below case:

```
$stmval = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM (SELECT col1, col2 FROM table ORDER BY col3 DESC LIMIT 5) tmp ORDER BY col3 ASC);
```

You'll get error cause middle SELECT wasn't including col3
Final correct code should be:

```
$stmval = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM (SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table ORDER BY col3 DESC LIMIT 5) tmp ORDER BY col3 ASC);
```