# mysql sub query with inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to select the 10 last rows from my table `messages`. I'm selecting the name and last name too from table `users` using `inner join`.

The thing is I need this rows in ascendant order, so I'm trying to use a subquery as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912770/select-last-20-order-by-ascending-php-mysql) post accepted answer.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT me.id, me.message, us.name1, us.lname1, SUBSTRING(us.lname2,1,1)
  FROM messages me INNER JOIN users us on me.rut=us.rut
  ORDER BY me.id DESC LIMIT 10
) tmp ORDER BY tmp.me.id ASC;
```

But it doesn't work, I actually don't know what's the proper way to do this with inner join.

Anyways, how can I make it work?

note: The inside parentesis query is working, it's just the outside parentesis query that doesn't work.

Comment: Probably you need  `ORDER BY tmp.id ASC;` instead of `ORDER BY tmp.me.id ASC;`

Answer (score 1):

In the outer query you will only *see* a `tmp.id` and not a `tmp.me.id`. So your oder clause should be

```
ORDER BY id
```

(As the `tmp.id` is the only one you can leave the `tmp.` away and `ORDER BY` implicitly uses `ASC`.)