# Order by and limit suggestions from stackoverflow doesn't work for me

Tags: php, mysql

I try to get the 10 latest entries from a table and at the end ordered ascending, so that the latest/newest entry is the last one I see.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT `title`, `content`, `message_id`
FROM `a_message_table`
WHERE `some-id` = 126
AND (`user_init_id` = 30 OR `user_follow_id` = 30)
ORDER BY `message_id`  DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

As suggested as answer for this question:
[Select last 20 order by ascending - PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912770/select-last-20-order-by-ascending-php-mysql)

I tried to modify my query like this:

```
(SELECT `title`, `content`, `message_id`
FROM `a_message_table`
WHERE `some-id` = 126
AND (`user_init_id` = 30 OR `user_follow_id` = 30)
ORDER BY `message_id`  DESC
LIMIT 0, 10)
ORDER BY `message_id` ASC
```

1.) Put the query into brackets

2.) add the line ORDER BY `message_id` ASC

Mysql reports the following errors:

1. This type of clause has been previously analyzed.(near "ORDER BY" at position 339)
2. unknown statement-type. (near "ORDER BY" at position 339)
3. #1054 - Unknown column 'message_id' in 'order clause'

I'm using mysql 5.7, mariaDB.

Someone can support here, to find an efficent way to get the latest ten entries of a table ordered so that the latest entry is the last one.

It is for a messaging system and I want that the user gets the latest entry when he scrolls down. When he scrolls up, he should get the next ten entries ordered like this. This is why I'm using LIMIT 0,10, later it says LIMIT 10, 10 and so on...

Comment: you could have sorted the records in array instead of fetching them using a query

Comment: At the End the entries are stored in a js array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Select * from 
(SELECT `title`, `content`, `message_id`
FROM `a_message_table`
WHERE `some-id` = 126
AND (`user_init_id` = 30 OR `user_follow_id` = 30)
ORDER BY `message_id`  DESC
LIMIT 0, 10) t
ORDER BY `t`.`message_id` ASC
```

Comment: I used exactly your query and instantly I get this errors:
1. An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 14)
Unexpected sign. (near "(" at position 14)
2. This type of clause has been previously analyzed. (near "SELECT" at position 17)
3. This type of clause has been previously analyzed. (near "ORDER BY" at position 361)
4. Unrecognized statement type. (near "ORDER BY" at position 361)

Maybe I use the wrong engine ore something like that? - I can't explain myself why this doesn't work for me. I'm pretty sure that your suggestion could work...

Comment: If `SELECT title, content, message_id
FROM a_message_table
WHERE some-id = 126
AND (user_init_id = 30 OR user_follow_id = 30)
ORDER BY message_id  DESC
LIMIT 0, 10` is working the above one will work.

Comment: The subquery does not work for me. Has it something todo with MariaDB I'm using?

Comment: Hm now it works, thanks! For security issues I was not able to name the exact row-names. I used aliases so the last line is ... ORDER BY `t`.`alias_name` ASC - my fault! Thank you, this works now!