# Mysql fetch from last to first - [many records]

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

i want to fetch records from mysql  starting from last to first LIMIT 20. my database have over 1M records. I am aware of order by. but from my understanding when using order by its taking forever to load 20 records i have no freaking idea. but i think mysql fetch all the records before ordering.

```
   SELECT bookings.created_at, bookings.total_amount,
    passengers.name, passengers.id_number, payments.amount,
    passengers.ticket_no,bookings.phone,bookings.source, 
    bookings.destination,bookings.date_of_travel FROM bookings 
    INNER JOIN passengers ON bookings.booking_id = passengers.booking_id 
    INNER JOIN payments on payments.booking_id = bookings.booking_id 
    ORDER BY bookings.booking_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Limit is a limit on the result set not on fetch from db.

Comment: @P.Salmon limit limit the records you can fetch

Comment: If you combine LIMIT row_count with ORDER BY, MySQL stops sorting as soon as it has found the first row_count rows of the sorted result, rather than sorting the entire result. If ordering is done by using an index, this is very fast. If a filesort must be done, all rows that match the query without the LIMIT clause are selected, and most or all of them are sorted, before the first row_count are found. After the initial rows have been found, MySQL does not sort any remainder of the result set.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you execute the query without the `order by` the time would be satisfactory?

You might try to create an index in the column your are ordering:

`create index idx_bookings_booking_id on bookings(booking_id)`

Comment: yes the time is satisfying but the result does not .... this is the problem. the database has over 1M records and i want to start fetching the records from last to first @Dio

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find out complexity of the Query using

```
EXPLAIN  SELECT bookings.created_at, bookings.total_amount,
    passengers.name, passengers.id_number, payments.amount,
    passengers.ticket_no,bookings.phone,bookings.source, 
    bookings.destination,bookings.date_of_travel FROM bookings 
    INNER JOIN passengers ON bookings.booking_id = passengers.booking_id 
    INNER JOIN payments on payments.booking_id = bookings.booking_id 
    ORDER BY bookings.booking_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

then check the proper index has been created on the table

```
SHOW INDEX FROM `db_name`.`table_name`;
```

if the index us not there create proper index on all the table

please add if anything is missing

Comment: the database index is available @Mahesh

Comment: Did u tried without join ? Try to get info . One more way is get the total count first , then remove sorting . Your limit will be limit (count-20),20

Comment: This is what i am doing for now, count all the rows subtract 20 from the total and fetch the records by  { WHERE >= count(*) - 20} ... working fine but this is not advisable. i hope there is a way i can start fetching records from  last to first

Answer (score 0):

The index lookup table needs to be able to reside in memory, if I'm not mistaken (filesort is much slower than in-mem lookup).

- Use small index / column size
- For a double in capacity use UNSIGNED columns if you need no negative values..
- Tune sort_buffer_size and read_rnd_buffer_size (maybe better on connection level, not global)
- See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html , particularly regarding using EXPLAIN and the maybe trying another execution plan strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need another workaround like materialized views.

Tell me if this sounds like it:

Create another table like the booking table e.g. CREATE TABLE booking_short LIKE booking. Though you only need the booking_id column

And check your code for where exactly you create booking orders, e.g. where you first insert into booking. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM booking_short. If it is >20, delete the first record. Insert the new booking_id.

You can select the ID and join from there before joining for more details with the rest of the tables.

You won't need limit or sorting.

Of course, this needs heavy documentation to avoid maintenance problems.

Either that or https://stackoverflow.com/a/5912827/6288442